# error in simple log in form in android studio java

Tags: java, android-studio

I am beginner. I have made a simple log in form in android studio. I face a fault in if condition. Please solve this.

If username box is empty then control should go in if(...) but it goes to else part and open next intent
code is here:

```
package com.android.dumbseraaz;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText uname;
    private EditText pwd;
    private Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_userName);
        pwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_Password);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

       login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validate(uname.getText().toString(),pwd.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private void validate(String myuname, String Pswd) {

       if(myuname == "")
        {
           uname.setText("user");
        }
        else if(Pswd == "")
         {
            pwd.setText("PasswordMe");
         }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, app_home.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```